# jquery attr get only class but not other attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to dynamically set an attribute to a div element and then get it back through jquery. the jquery attr method works when i try to get the class but returns undefined when i try other attributes. this is i have tried,
my php code

```
while($records = mysqli_fetch_assoc($parcel)){
                echo "<div class='records'  id='".$records['id']."' code='".$records['Tracking_code']."'>
                <div class='record'>".$records['Sender_name']."</div> 
                <div class='record'>".$records['Tracking_code']."</div>
                <div class='record'>".$records['Parcel_location']."</div> 
                <div class='record'>".$records['Parcel_status']."</div>
                <div class='record btn-record'><a class='btn-record' href='updateRecord.php?id=".$records['id']."&trackId=".$records['Tracking_code']."'>Edit</a></div> 
                <div class='record btn-record'><a class='btn-record' href='parceldetail.php?id=".$records['id']."&trackId=".$records['Tracking_code']."'>View</a></div>   
            </div><br />";
```

this is my jquery code

```
    "use strict";
$('.records').on('click', function(e){
        let code = $(this).attr('code');
        let uid = $(this).data('id');
        console.log(code);
        window.location.replace(`updaterecord?id=${uid}&&trackId=${code}`);
    })

});
```

both the code and uid return undefined. please help. what am i doing wrong

Comment: I'd recommend that you use data attributes instead of adding your custom attributes.  Data attributes are meant for this purpose.

Comment: `attr('code')` should work fine (even if it is not a valid attribute) so there is something wrong with your `$records['Tracking_code']` (incorrect item name perhaps? Bear in mind keys in an array are case sensitive) - you would be better sharing outputted HTML. Also it should be `$(this).attr('id')` not `.data`. As devlin carnate suggested, for `code=` change it to `data-code=` and use `$(this).data('code')` instead

Comment: when i use data attributes it also returns undefined.@devlin carnate

Comment: @GrahamRitchie my $records['Tracking_code'] is correct. i even added a string in place of the variable. it also returned undefined

Comment: Please share the outputted HTML, **there is something not right there**, the JS you wrote for `code` is correct assuming everything outputs correctly. As I said the JS you wrote to get the `uid` is wrong and I explained how to fix that one. Put a code snippet in your question or a fiddle in the comments (with the outputted HTML not the PHP) and we will be able to help you further. If there are hundreds of records / sensitive data just create two sample rows in a fiddle. This will help us check your JS and make sure that is right so you can rule that out.